# How come no one noticed Logan's bullet hole?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2000

At the end of *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, Logan got shot in the head with an Adamantium Bullet which was the only thing strong enough to get though his Adamantium bones.

Is it explained how no one noticed in the first *X-Men* movie that he had a bullet hole in his "indestructible" skull when Xavier learned his **entire** skeleton was made of Adamantium?

Comment: How Wolverine lost his memories was not important in the 2000 movie
 and thus not mentioned?

Comment: More importantly - Riddle me this: How can an indestructible bullet get through an indestructible skull?  They are both made of the same material, a material that we have seen (in claw form) can actually deflect bullets... So how does this all-of-a-sudden work?

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_--m033SEOw#t=180

Comment: @calccrypto - Fun movie, of course, but not the same thing.  If adamantium worked like that both Cyber and Sabretooth would have been able to penetrate Wolvie's laced skeleton at some point... not to mention Lady Deathstrike at the speed her robotic arms move.

Comment: So there is a logical flaw in the X-Men movies? How shocking... I think to remember through that Xavier told Wolverine in the first movie that he had to find out by himself. So maybe he knew about the hole and added 1+1 and came to the conclusion that Wolverines brain was "erased by bullet".

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza A bullet that didn't deform on impact would apply a larger force for a shorter time in a smaller area (but the same overall impulse) assuming its travelling at the same speed with the same weight as a regular bullet. This would give it more penetrating power (lead in regular bullets is quite soft, but its also very dense which gives it an edge)

Comment: @user20310 - You have failed to convince me.  I'd say Lady Deathstrike packs a lot of force with her bionic adamantium arms that project from her body at high speeds... If only Logan had been shot in the eye we wouldn't need to make up physics to explain the terrible ending to a terrible movie.

Comment: I don't remember it ever actually showing that the bullet *pierced* the adamantium shell over his skull, merely that it had enough force to cause severe enough trauma that it impared his healing in such a way that his memories where affected.

Answer (score 0):

Shoddy storytelling really.
They needed a way for wolverine to lose his memories, and didn't think of what consequences this would have for the earlier movies.

On the topic of why the bullet was able to penetrate his skull: it was made of adamantium.
The layer of adamantium on Wolverine's skull is not very thick, or we'd see it through his skin.
If the bullet was pointy (AKA: specifically made to penetrate material) it would've gone through his skull easily, since it's the same material.

Comment: Isn't then a possible explanation that the skullbone was intact and that just no one noticed because it looked all the same in xray/mrt/crt/whatever?

Comment: I vaguely recall storm and professor X looking at a picture of Logan's skeleton, including the adamantium. They should have seen a hole but they didn't. Maybe it appeared asif there was no hole because it was a 2D picture.